# Flex builder3 is not generating html wrapper when targeting flex 4 sdk

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex4

In Flex builder 3 when I create a new flex application targeting the flex 4 sdk, it wont generate a html wrapper file.

I have hunted around the web for answers, but no success. I have made sure the box is checked in the project properties to generate html wrapper.

The only workaround is to target an older version of the sdk (i.e. 3.2), which will cause the wrapper to be generated. Then I can revert the project to sdk 4. This then means I can never do a clean of my project because this will result in the wrapper being deleted.

Has anyone else come across this? Is this just a bug with Flexbuilder3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug with using the flex 4 sdk inside flex builder 3. My solution was to upgrade to Flash Builder 4 which has a much nicer integration between the project and the flex sdk.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the project area folder called "html-template" from the Flex Navigator Panel within Flex3. This folder may be empty. You should have 2 files in here:

- index.template.html
- swobject.js

These will help you generate the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I beat my head against this a bit and after look all over the net I combined a few solutions and finally came up with one that works for me. Try this to get it to work with with out up grading to Flash Builder 4:

STEP 1
Navigate to your Flex 3 SDK and copy the following folders from YOUR 3.0 SDK PATH\templates\ to YOUR 4.0 SDK PATH\Templates\ .

-- Client-side-detection

-- Client-side-detection-with-history

-- Express-installation

-- Express-installation-with-history

-- No-player-detection

-- No-playerdetection-with-history

Note: Greg Lafrance recommends an addition folder "Swfobject" in his instructions over at ADOBE, but I didn't need that one myself.

STEP 2
Go to File -> Switch Workspace -> Other and create a COMPLETELY NEW workspace ( i.e: I called my Flex 4).

STEP 3
Create new project. Right Click it -> Flex Compiler -> Configure Flex SDKS's -> Add... -> Navigate to your Flex 4 SDK and add it. Click Ok. DO STEP 4 BEFORE CLOSING THE PROPERTIES.

Step 4.
Change "Require Flash Player Version" to 10.0.0 .

Step 5. 
Click OK and erase the  based code and copy over FLEX 4 Code with spark elements and what not.

Good Luck, Hope this helps someone out there in internet land who Googles this question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post.  I was wondering if you also had issues with code completion and package imports (using Ctrl-Space) for the flash.* packages?  I posted this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350003/how-to-fix-code-hinting-in-flex-builder-3-when-upgrading-to-sdk-4-0-or-4-1 and it is the only bug that seems to be left when using flex builder 3 with the 4.1 or 4.0 flex SDK.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me like this way.....i changed Project->properties->FlexCompilerchosed sdk flex-3 rather than flex4(my current version) then clean and build i got the html and .swf files after that i switched to SDK - Flex 4 and i ran my mxml file without any error

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse `Problems` view, there will be one problem `Cannot create HTML wrapper. Right-click here to recreate folder html-template.` . Right click on the problem and choose `Recreate HTML Templates`.