# Flex: HTML file not getting generated

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

The project I am working on uses Cairngorm Architecture of flex. I am able to build and run the application perfectly on my local host. But, When I am deploying this code in my server "Main.html" is not being generated.

I am moving the code to some location in my server. Executing Build file and then trying to run the application.

I am using Flex 3.5 version of SDK and 10.0.0 version of Flash Player.

I did refer to the following link but it didn't help.

[Flex builder3 is not generating html wrapper when targeting flex 4 sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342934/flex-builder3-is-not-generating-html-wrapper-when-targeting-flex-4-sdk)

I am unable to identify the cause. Kindly help me in resolving the issue.

Thank you,
Pri

Comment: How are you deploying your code?  What does your build file look like?

Answer (score 0):

The main.html file is generated by flash builder during the compilation of your application. It is not generated by your application itself.

So you you have to generate it locally, then copy both your swf and you main.html file on your server.

Comment: The build file i have first compiles the application so ideal it should generate the the swf and html file.

Comment: The HTML file genrated by Flash Builder does not contain anything specific to your application. It is meant to provide you a sample HTML file, to allow you to test your application easily, and to show you how to insert a swf into a web page if you are not familiar with this. Usually you customize this page, or you don't even use it. In your case you should copy the HTML using the build file (an ant build.xml I assume). However something is surprising me. Why are you deploying your source on your server? Is it a Continous Integration server?